# Make a div 30px less than the div it is contained in

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div inside of another div. The outer div has a percentage width (80%), and I want the inner div to have 30px less width than the width of the outer div. How do I do this? I'm assuming I'll need to use javascript?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add a 15px margin on both sides

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use margins :

```
​<div style="width:80%;"> 
    <div style="margin-left:15px;margin-right:15px;"> inner </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/gsRBS/)

Comment: It was so obvious!! Thank you very much :]

Answer (score 0):

@dystroy has a very good answer, though it lacks dynamic customization.

My take, use CSS variables.

You'll have to do something like this:

```
#parent-div
{
    var-width: 100px; /* Or something else? */
    //Notice that though the attribute is named var-width, the browser will
    //treat it as width and will use the `var-` prefix as directive
    //so that the calculations can be performed by using it as variable.
}
#child-div
{
    width: calc(var(width) - 30);
}
```

This will make the CSS calculate the child's width.

More on this, [here.](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/css-variables/)